# Tkinter Multiple GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hey I am having a problem during connecting two Gui together as when button pressed i want the tkinter to open another gui from another file.

File one contains the frontend dashboard and when you click on the teacher than click on login it gives me an error saying.

`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'`

this is the main page Source Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from login import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk    

class Frontend(tk.Tk):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title('Portal') # set the title of the main window
        self.geometry('300x300') # set size of the main window to 300x300 pixels

        # this container contains all the pages
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)   # make the cell in grid cover the entire window
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1) # make the cell in grid cover the entire window
        self.frames = {} # these are pages we want to navigate to

        for F in (Dashboard, Teacher, Student): # for each page
             frame = F(container, self) # create the page
             self.frames[F] = frame  # store into frames
             frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew') # grid it to container    
             self.show_frame(Dashboard) # let the first page is Dashboard

     def show_frame(self, name):
         frame = self.frames[name]
         frame.tkraise()

class Dashboard(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Main Screen", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Teacher",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Teacher))
        button.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Student",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Student))
        button1.pack()


class Teacher(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Teacher Login", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        #logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('logo.png'))

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Login", command=LoginFrame)
        button.pack()


        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Home",
        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Dashboard))
        button1.pack()


class Student(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Student Login", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Dashboard))
        button.pack()

def main():
   root = Frontend()
   root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Login source code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm


class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label_username = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_password = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_username = Entry(self)
        self.entry_password = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_username.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.checkbox = Checkbutton(self, text="Keep me logged in")
        self.checkbox.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command=self._login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.pack()

    def _login_btn_clicked(self):
        # print("Clicked")
        username = self.entry_username.get()
        password = self.entry_password.get()

        # print(username, password)

        if username == "admin" and password == "admin123":
            tm.showinfo("Login info", "Welcome Admin")
        else:
            tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username")

def main():
    root = Tk()
    page = LoginFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks

Comment: In `LoginFrame.__init__()`, you failed to pass on the `self` parameter to the superclass.  You did it right in all of your other classes.

Comment: when I pass self parameter to the superclass i get this error page = LoginFrame()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'
>>>

Comment: You need both parameters.

Comment: Yea I have added both of them self and master into  super().__init__(self, master) but it's gives out that error for some reason

Comment: This `command=LoginFrame` is invalid. You can't pass a `class` object as `command=`. Create a `def login(...` within `Class Teacher` and do `command=self.login`. Within `def login(...` create a Instance of `class LoginFrame`.